# PropertyGrid with custom Itemsource and Dependency Injection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dependency-injection, propertygrid, xceed

I'm using Ninject in an MVVM application which contains a Xceed PropertyGrid. The PropertyGrid should use a custom ItemSource for one particular property currently defined with an Attribute:

```
[ItemSource(GetType(SomeObjectItemSource)]
```

The SomeObjectItemSource.GetValues would look like that and need's access to an object created with Ninject

```
Public Function GetValues() As ItemCollection Implements IItemsSource.GetValues

    Fetch RootObject from Ninject Kernel
    Extract a list of SomeObject from RootObject and Return

End Function
```

As the PropertyGrid is not created by Ninject and Ninject internally uses   Activator.CreateInstance without any optional constructor parameters this approach fails as I cannot pass a reference to the Ninject kernel or to RootObject.

Note: The source of the PropertyGrid looks like this. Activate.CreateInstance would be able to use the constructor, but it isn't implemented that way.

```
private System.Collections.IEnumerable CreateItemsSource()
{
  var instance = Activator.CreateInstance( _attribute.Type );
  return ( instance as IItemsSource ).GetValues();
}
```

Alternatively it would be possible to use a custom type editor using ITypeEditor and binding the editor to a property of the instance which created the PropertyGrid. The approach is suggested here: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/351513 and looks like:

```
Public Class SomeObjectTypeEditor
  Implements ITypeEditor
  Public Function ResolveEditor(propertyItem As PropertyItem) As FrameworkElement
    Dim box As New ComboBox() With { _
     .DisplayMemberPath = "SomeObject" _
    }

    Dim itemSourcebinding = New Binding("") With { _
        .Source = MainWindow.ListOfSomeObject , _
        .ValidatesOnExceptions = True, _
        .ValidatesOnDataErrors = True, _
        .Mode = BindingMode.OneWay _
    }
  End Function
End Class
```

If I want to stick to avoiding code behind I the only feasible way I see is using property injection on MainWindow.ListOfSomeObject. However this does not look right to me.

I also guess that such situations will arise with different controls as well. Is there a common, abstract approach on solving such issues for all WPF controls?

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution I found is to use a editing template and bind to a property of the ViewModel.

```
<xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox Name="Combo" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ListOfSomeObject}"
                                             DisplayMemberPath="ObjectName"
                                             SelectedValuePath="ObjectID" />
    </DataTemplate>
</xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
```

Using this approach ListOfSomeObject can be created using property injection or directly with constructor injection.